# Equalizing height of elements inside flexbox columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a table with several columns. Those columns can contain differently-size content so the height varies.

What I want to do is to adjust the height of the single elements to make it look like this image:

[image: this image].

```css
.table {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #B2EBF2;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
}

.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    width: 33%;
}

.box {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #546E7A;
}

.title {
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

.description {
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="box title">
                    Test 1
                </div>
                <div class="box description">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                </div>
                <div class="box image">
                    <img src="http://unsplash.it/300/320" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="box title">
                    Test 2
                </div>
                <div class="box description">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                </div>
                <div class="box image">
                    <img src="http://unsplash.it/300/300" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="box title">
                    Test 3
                </div>
                <div class="box description">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
                </div>
                <div class="box image">
                    <img src="http://unsplash.it/300/280" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should use images of the same sizes. Then remove the flex: 1 0 auto; from the .box, but give flex: 1 0 auto; only to .description.
I hope it could satisfy all your requirements.